# Resolution problem in 5 inch screen

Tags: hdmi, screen

I have one 5" screen, when I connect it to my Raspberry Pi see like this:

[image: ScreenfromPi]

But when I connect it to my computer the screen works well:

[image: ScreenfromPC]

I tried with change the parameter in [video section](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) in config.txt document
from 1 which means 4:3

```
sdtv_aspect=1
```

to 3 which means 16:9

```
sdtv_aspect=3
```

but didn't work.

Please help I needto work with the complete screen.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: sdtv_aspect changes the aspect ratio of composite video output ... but I'm speculating that you are in fact using HDMI - what are the *relevant* settings in config.txt set to?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using HDMI. And don´t know why the screen looks like that. :(

Comment: what are the relevant settings in config.txt set to

Comment: I have no idea, that is the reason I asked here :(

Comment: if you have no idea of the contents of *your* `config.txt`, how do you expect us to know

Comment: Wait I don't understand you. I have the basic config.txt and I only made a change in sdtv_aspect assuming it was the solution but no. So I'm asking here if someone knows what contents can I change to make it work

Comment: ahh, see, I was asking you what *your* `config.txt` looked like - but as you've made no (other) changes to the "default", that answers the question too :p

Comment: start a `terminal` .. what is the output of `tvservice --modes=CEA` and `tvservice --modes=DMT`